# How to make a transition start when hovering another div?

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to coding...

```
<div class="box">
<a href="#">Click Here</a>
<div class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my code. I am trying to get "slide" to start a transition when I hover over the entire"box". As it is now I have to hover over the actual div.

Here it is in jsfiddle. I've been using LESS, can you not use it in jsfiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/nntTn/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you question is descriptive enough and/or your jsfiddle is incorrect. COuld you do a better job explaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nntTn/2/

You just had the wrong selector is all for this

So I changed this

```
.box .slide:hover {
  left: 262px;
}
```

to this

```
.box:hover .slide {
  left: 262px;
}
```

and it works great now.

Answer (score 1):

On line 32 of your fiddle, change to:

```
.box:hover .slide {
```